# NLC Classifier Limits

Tags: ibm-cloud

Regarding NLC service classifiers, when adding a 9th classifier to an NLC service, the following error occurs:
"This user or service instance has the maximum number of classifiers"

I am assuming this means that the limit for the number of classifiers a free user can create is 8. 
If we upgraded our account, would that limit be increased?

Answer (score 0):

Kawashima-san, you can get this kind of question answered by [contacting Bluemix support](https://support.ng.bluemix.net/technicalsupport/) (select "Cognitive" for question type). Stack Overflow is the right place for questions about programming with the Bluemix Platform and Services. Questions about the offerings, pricing, getting started, etc. can be asked from Support or at the [IBM developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/) forum.

Comment: Thank you. I'll ask on the IBM developerWorks Answers.